# Docker container for QGIS Server with PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgresql, docker

As of now, we are using the QGIS locally to inspect the PostgreSQL data.
We need to set up the docker container together with the PostgreSQL database. I have created a docker-compose file for this setup as below.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  postgres:
    build: .
    restart: always
    labels:
      com.datadoghq.ad.logs: >-
        [{"source": "postgresql", "service": "postgresql", "sourcecategory":
        "database", "log_processing_rules": [{"type": "multi_line", "name":
        "new_log_start_with_date", "pattern":
        "\\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"}]}]
    command: postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - './conf:/etc/postgresql/conf:ro'
      - './data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - postgres
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - '82:80'
    volumes:
      - './pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin'
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: postgres@admin.de
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    networks:
      - postgres
  qgisserver:
    image: 'camptocamp/qgis-server:latest'
    container_name: docker_app_qgis
    volumes:
      - '/home/admin/qgis-server/projects:/etc/qgisserver'
    ports:
      - '8380:80'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

When I do the `docker-compose up` all the docker containers are up. After hitting the URL in the browser `http://192.168.20.134:8380/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/home/admin/qgis-server/projects`

and/or `http://192.168.20.134:8380` I am getting the below error.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ServerException>Project file error. For OWS services: please provide a SERVICE and a MAP parameter pointing to a valid QGIS project file</ServerException>
```

How should I access the QGIS desktop through the docker container on the web browser?

Comment: your question asks about Qgis desktop but the error is coming from Qgis server - which are you actually using

Comment: @IanTurton yes, I have edited the question. It is for QGIS server.